# Convert Matlab m files into C/C++ codes using Matlab Coder, including mex files (mxArray)

Tags: c++, c, matlab, matlab-coder

I'm using Matlab Coder to generate **C/C++** codes from a matlab `.m` file, which calls external **C/C++** functions. I did some work and found "`code.ceval`" made it worked.

But it gets complicated when the `.m` file calls external `mex-files` (with mxArray). Fortunately I have the original **C/C++** codes for the mex-files.

Could anyone tell me how to include mex-files (with mxArray inputs/outputs) when generating **C/C++** codes using Matlab Coder, or give me an example?

Best,
Yours, Cong

Answer (score 1):

mex files need to be run with MATLAB. They cannot be run outside MATLAB. If you are generating mex files using MATLAB coder you can call other mex and MATLAB functions using coder.extrinsic. Otherwise you can only call regular C functions.

Comment: Thanks Navan. Yes, sure, mex files can only be run in MATLAB. But I have the C/C++ codes for them. So, I should be able to incorporate them as external C/C++ codes. The only thing is to write interfaces. Any idea?

Comment: Even with C/C++ files if you are using mx function calls they are not going to work. For example creation of mxArrays using mxCreate* API can work only through MATLAB.

Comment: It seems not. mxArrays can work with C/C++ environment